# Raspberry pi 2 to Windows 10 SFTP/SSH

Tags: pi-2

I am trying to connect my windows 10 pc with raspberry pi 2 using python script.
What I want to do: I want to download the file from windows 10 machine with the help of python Script from raspberry pi. I dont want to use ftp.

What I am doing: I have written the code using paramiko. Below are my code.

```
import os

import paramiko

host = "192.168.1.9"                    
port = 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))

password = "mypassword"                
username = "myusername"                        
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)

sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

But I am not able to connect only. Its saying connection refused error.

Note: I have connected locally from pi as well as windows means both systems are in same network.

Please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Can you connect using ssh or sftp from the command line?  You really only get one chance to get your question seen, you need to make sure you include all relevant detail up front rather than just in response to comments.

Comment: There isn't a ssh, scp nor sftp service running on a default MS-Windows installation. You have to install and enable those first.

Comment: I am trying to connect using ssh or sftp from the command line also but not able to do so.

Comment: Hi Janka Can you let me know how to do that.

Comment: If you want to use SSH - first install the "windows 10 built in openssh server" - hint that's what you need to search for on the intergoogles

Comment: Hi Jaromanda, I have installed the "windows 10 built in openssh server" and able to do ssh from windows to raspberry pi but not able to do vice versa. I tried with the paramiko also and its throwing Paramiko.SSHException: Unable to connect to .... [Errorno 110] Connection time out.

Comment: perhaps you need to add firewall rules in windows to allow an incoming connection on port 22

Comment: @ Jaromanda Already made the changes in firewall rules in windows to allow an incoming connection on port 22 but still not working

Comment: just to be clear ... you **can** ssh from pi to windows? and **sftp** from pi to windows using command line?

Comment: if not, start the *OpenSSH SSH Service*

Comment: Thanks for the help  Jaromanda. I have tried every thing but still not working anyways I am doing some R&D and if it works then I am going to post the solution.